# Access sitecore settings programmatically (Sitecore 6)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Is there a way to get to sitecore settings through code.

The specific setting I'm interested in is the data Folder path.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes. Look at the Sitecore.Configuration.Settings class (which is your entry point to the Sitecore settings), and use the static DataFolder property:

```cs
string dataFolder = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.DataFolder;
```

Answer (score 31):

If you'd like to get other settings, you may want to try:-

```cs
Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("SettingName");
```

This will work for all sitecore settings, even your custom settings that can be added through the config files in the App_config/Include.

Comment: I enjoy that this is not the correct answer to this problem, but because of the ambiguity of the question, many people who needed this answer (myself included) end up here. +1

Comment: hi @sean i'm i'm trying to get setting in same manner as you described,
it giving me an error when i'm evaluating result.

Comment: @Amitavin what's the error you're getting? This should work if you have a Sitecore setting in your webconfig (or App_Config/Include configs). Make sure it's a Sitecore setting and you can see it when you access the /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx page).